# Destroy all other states when go to an specified state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

Hi I have an application made in Ionic and AngularJS that have a login view and many other views that are show only after the user login (With his Fb account or as a guest).

I have some bugs relating to the change of account type (Fb, Guest) and I think all this problems can be solve destroying the state of all other controller when the user logout of his account and re-created when the user login.

How can I do that?

PostData: Everytime I login into the application a new instance of the controller are created so if I login 20 times 20 controller of the same type will be created...

I really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply **cache:false** in your route

```
.state('some_page', {
  url: "/page1",
  cache:false, // add this line and it'll works!!
  views: {
    'some-tab': {
      templateUrl: "templates/page1.html",
      controller: "PageCtrl"
    }
  }
});
```